# Discarding parsed lines from read chunks of text from a process' memory

Tags: c++, memory

This is the first bigger thing I'm writing in C++, and I can't quite wrap my head around the problem I stumbled upon. I'm reading strings from a process' memory with the following snippet:

```
auto entries = std::vector<std::string>();
auto msg_node_addr = reader.readPtr(tab_msg_data_struct +
                                    DATA_STRUCT_NODE_OFFSET);
/*
 * Loop through message nodes,
 * and retrieve information at given offset.
 */
while (msg_node_addr != 0x0) {
    auto msg_content_ptr = reader.readPtr(msg_node_addr +
                                          NODE_CONTENT_PTR_OFFSET);
    auto msg_content = reader.readStr(msg_content_ptr, 255);
    auto has_timestamp = !msg_content.empty()
                         && std::isdigit(msg_content[0])
                         && std::isdigit(msg_content[1])
                         && msg_content[2] == ':';

    if (has_timestamp) {
        entries.emplace_back(msg_content);
    }

    // Advance to next node.
    msg_node_addr = reader.readPtr(msg_node_addr +
                                   DATA_STRUCT_NODE_STEP_OFFSET);
}
```

which resides in a function that returns the vector of entries.
Every entry is of the following form:

```
12:31 Loot of a <creature>: <loot>
```

I call the function, get the current chunk of messages, and retrieve needed values from them. Now, when I call it again, there'll always be some values that I've already taken care of, and new ones.

For example, this would be the result after the first call:

```
15:30 Loot of a <creature>: <loot>
15:30 Loot of a <creature>: <loot>
15:31 Loot of a <creature>: <loot>
```

And this, after the second one:

```
15:30 Loot of a <creature>: <loot> <- Old value.
15:30 Loot of a <creature>: <loot> <- Old value.
15:31 Loot of a <creature>: <loot> <- Old value.
15:31 Loot of a <creature>: <loot> <- New one.
15:32 Loot of a <creature>: <loot>
```

How could I discard the already parsed strings? Comparing timestamps doesn't seem to be an option as they don't even include seconds.

Comment: I don't think you're code's got enough of the surrounding calls, callers, etc. to be able to answer the question properly. I'd like to say do something like make `msg_node_addr` static or put a `last_accessed_addr` in `reader`, but I don't know enough about the rest of the code, or the design.

Comment: @user2475059 `reader` is just a wrapper class around calls to WinAPI. I would like to mark the message where I "took off" during the last call, and start from that point during the next one.

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar enough with the structure of the code, but the approach I think I would take is to just store the `last_accessed_addr` somehow, then only return everything after that. Even then, there's a lot of ways to do *that* (static function-scope variable, class member variable, return value tracking of some kind, bundling the string with its address in the process and computing with a helper function), so without other code to get a sense of which way might be best, I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try creating a variable `static auto last_msg_node_addr = msg_node_address;` before you initially enter the while loop and after the `auto msg_node_addr = reader.readPtr(tab_msg_data_struct + DATA_STRUCT_NODE_OFFSET);` statement, then before the `msg_node_addr = reader.readPtr(msg_node_addr + DATA_STRUCT_NODE_STEP_OFFSET);` at the end of the loop place the line `last_msg_node_addr = msg_node_addr;`. Since the variable is static, it should maintain its value between function calls. You would just need to modify the function to check the value of `last_msg_ptr` upon entering the function and before it is updated.

Also, you said,

> How could I discard the already parsed strings? Comparing timestamps doesn't seem to be an option as they don't even include seconds.

That would depend on how you're storing the strings, but I think it would need to be part of your parsing routine.

Comment: Both of you had the right ideas, I completely forgot about the existence of static variables, thanks!

Comment: If this is going in a threaded environment (it's clearly at least a multiprocess environment), then beware of threading issues around static variables. At least, I *think* it's problematic; I don't do multiple threads much.